# Socket.io Node - React connection false

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I'm not able to connect to socket on client for some reason. Logging socket all the time returns False. I tried official Socket.io app and it is working fine.. Can anyone help and let me know what I'm missing here?

**Server**

```
const app = require('express')()
const http = require('http').Server(app)
const io = require('socket.io')()

const router = require('./router')

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('user connected');

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('user disconnected');
    })
})

app.use(router)

app.listen(PORT, () => {console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`)})
```

**Client**

```
import queryString from 'query-string'
import io from 'socket.io-client'

let socket;

const Chat = () => {
    const ENDPOINT = 'http://localhost:8080'
    useEffect(() => {
        socket = io(ENDPOINT)
        console.log(socket);

    })

    return (
        <div>
            Chat
        </div>
    )
}

export default Chat
```

**Solution**

Server is listening on app instead http.listen(...)

Answer (score 1):

You should pass `http` into socket.io:

```
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
```

Comment: Probably worth explaining that the variable named `http` in your answer and in the OP's code is the HTTP server object.  That's what you pass to socket.io so that it can hook into your existing http server.

Comment: Tried also with http passed, but still no logs from neither server or client.

Answer (score 0):

Try using your ip address instead of the localhost

Comment: Tried with 127.0.0.1:8080, but still nothing